# Call to a method from location listener doesn't seem to work!

Tags: android, service, geolocation, location

I've implemented a locationListener and I want every time the location is changed to call a method from within the onLocationChanged method.

The location listener is implemented as a class within a service. Everything seems to be working fine when the app is in the foreground but when its not I receive updates I call the method but I realised after debugging that it doesnt get inside the method for some reason.

My LocationListener:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {       
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("----ADS SERVICE LOCATION LISTENER-------", "LOCATION UPDATE");
            contactServer(location);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {            
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {           
        }
    }
```

And this is where it gets stuck...Doesnt go through to the body of the method

```
private void contactServer(Location location){
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I could put all the code in the onLocationChanged method but it should really be in a separate method as its very long and not really relevant!

Comment: There is no way that your Log.d() is executing but the call to contactServer() does not. When and how are you starting and stopping your service?

Comment: @Reuben Log.d() is definitely executing...it  gets printed in the log and i debugged it as well...put a breakpoint in the contactServer line and it did stop there..I'm starting the service the moment I launch the app and Im not stopping it at all at the moment!

Comment: Don't trust your debugger 100%. Sprinkle some Log.d()s in your contactServer(), check that they appear...

Comment: @Reuben Yeah I'll try that as soon as I go home.Its really weird though.Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: @Reuben Took me a while to look into that but it works!!! I put some log.d() in the method as you suggested and they actually print..donno whats wrong with the debugger..Put that as an answer I'll accept it so that you get the reputation points..cheers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments on the question, the problem is not that code never runs but that the debugger somehow failed to allow it to be stepped through.